# In a firefox theme, how do I change the default background color of a window?

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, xul

Searching in the Mozilla `classic.jar`, I found a `dialog.css` (at `../classic/global/dialog.css`), but no `window.css` nither `panel.css`.

So, where am I suppose to change the default background-color of a window in my theme?

Obs. I mean not only the main browser window, but any window that opens with no specified background-color, I want to change the default color.

Answer (score 1):

The CSS for the window is in `global.css` which I already linked you to in another answer. The CSS for a panel is in `popup.css`.